# Transitions ignores border radius in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a button that changes background color on hover. During the transition period, FF ignores the border-radius and display a square instead until the animation finishes.
Is there a mozilla specific property I can set that would fix this?  I'm using FF 78.12 on linux.

```css
#sidebar{border-right:1px solid #111;background:#222;float:left;padding:0;padding-top:40px;}
#sidebar a{display:block;transition:all 0.1s linear;color:#CCC;height:40px;line-height:40px;text-decoration:none;padding-left:10px;font-weight:bold;}

#sidebar-toggle{
        border-radius:30px;
        border-width:0;
        width:30px;
        height: 45px;       
        background:#555;
        color:#999;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        position:relative;
        float:right;
    left: 15px;
        top:calc(50% - 35px - 90px);
        z-index:10;
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);

    }

    #sidebar-toggle:hover{background:#09d8e3}
    #sidebar-toggle:focus{outline:none;}
```

```html
    <div id="sidebar" style="width:200px;height:100vh">
        <button type="button" id="sidebar-toggle" class="toggle-offset" >X</button>
        <a href="">Menu Thingy</a>
        <a href="">Groups</a>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
        <a href="">Calendar</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's fine on my WIndows10 Firefox (92.0.1).

Comment: Thanks, I'll go yell at the admins to update our repo!